# Getting a 'failed to push some refs to github' error when I try to push new changes to github

Tags: github, repository, git-branch, git-push, refs

Hello I am getting an error everytime I try to push my changes to github. I have tried reading other similar questions on stack overflow but none of the solutions are working for me

```
~/SkillSwap/skill_swap_client // ♥ > git add src/index.js
~/SkillSwap/skill_swap_client // ♥ > git commit -m "remove unneceassary import"
[my-branch 68c3622] remove unneceassary import
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
~/SkillSwap/skill_swap_client // ♥ > git push
To github.com:Sehrish88/SkillSwap.git
 ! [rejected]        my-branch -> my-branch (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:Sehrish88/SkillSwap.git'
```

Comment: Hi Sehrish, can you post a more extensive log? Very likely the remote branch contains changes that your local branch still doesn't have